Testing MT5 summarization model fine-tuned on Xl-sum arabic dataset gave bad results
I wonder Why the summarization model ("csebuetnlp/mT5_multilingual_XLSum") gave good summary when testing it on Arabic samples, but when testing the fine-tuned model on the XL-SUM dataset for 10 epochs, it didn't give good results. the output summary is a mix of special character, Arabic words and rubbish, and it is not understandable. Although the rouge measures are good during fine-tuning, the training and validation losses are close to zero. I also used the same tokenizer for both fine-tuning and testing.

Welcome to SO! This isn't my field, but I just wanted to mention, this is not the place for urgent help. If you want to get a good answer fast, ask a good question. That might include writing a title that's actually a question (see [ask]) and providing example code (see [mre]).
